# Can I render from Top when using FlatList inverted?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
          inverted
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
        <Text>123</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Using `inverted FlatList` will render item from bottom to top when data is small.

When I run my expo snack
a and b are at the bottom.
I want this to start at the top.

Using the `inverted` option of `FlatList`
Can I render from top when data is small?

https://snack.expo.io/r1eZBINGH

It does not matter if the `inverted` is removed if it is rendered at the top and the scroll can start at the bottom.
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
          inverted
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
        <Text>123</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I solved it by setting `contentContainerStyle`.
Using fullscreen with `flexGrow: 1` and `justifyContent: 'flex-end'` in the `inverted` state seems to start at the top when the data is small.

Comment: Thanks, i was searching for this for a long time.

Comment: Thanks, I also, I still was thinking is something to do with container, many thanks for sharing solution

Comment: Thanks! I think FlatList should have considered this situation