# Can I render from Top when using FlashList inverted?

Tags: react-native, flash-list

[Can I render from Top when using FlatList inverted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161189/can-i-render-from-top-when-using-flatlist-inverted)

I was able to render from the top of an inverted list usinh a Flatlist for the method above. The Flashlist contentContainerStyle does not seem to support flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
 <View style={this.props.alignTop ? styles.containerAlignTop : styles.container}>
   // Flashlist
 </View>
```

Style Sheet

```
  containerAlignTop: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  }
```